# How does php behave on initialized parameters?

Tags: php

Lets assume I have the following function:

```
function myTest($param = false){
echo $param;
}
```

And now I have the following call to the function

```
myTest($test);
```

However, $test wasnt declared yet by the moment the call is made. Will php throw an error?

I ask because I have a process where it is possible that some variables aren't instantiated before the call where they are used is made. In theory, this is okay, because I have a default behavior inside these functions handling this case (thats why Im initializing the functions parameter). However, if php throws an error in this case, then I have to build a workaround (which will be ugly ^^), but before doing so, I wanted to ask you :D

Comment: It will throw an error when you try to access the value of `$test` in the line `myTest($test)`, and there is no variable `$test` defined. It doesn't matter whether you want to pass it to a function or anything else or what the function's signature is; the act of trying to get a value from an undefined variable is an error.

Comment: You'll get an undefined variable notice. Your `$parma = false` prevents `myTest()` from generating an error.

Comment: okay, thank you! :=) Besides, does the same hold true for javascript? (assume the same case as showcased above)

Comment: Javascript behaves very differently in this regard, don't even mix this into this topic.

Comment: Effectively, you will get a notice. If you are using PHP7, you will be able to do `myTest($test ?? false)` but I think it is probably better to initialize all your variables before. I said that just for information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get an error, but a warning. See [variable basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

> It is not necessary to initialize variables in PHP however it is a very good practice. **Uninitialized variables have a default value of their type depending on the context in which they are used** - booleans default to FALSE, integers and floats default to zero, strings (e.g. used in echo) are set as an empty string and arrays become to an empty array.

**Example: Default values of uninitialized variables**

```
<?php
// Unset AND unreferenced (no use context) variable; outputs NULL
var_dump($unset_var);

// Boolean usage; outputs 'false' (See ternary operators for more on this syntax)
echo($unset_bool ? "true\n" : "false\n");

// String usage; outputs 'string(3) "abc"'
$unset_str .= 'abc';
var_dump($unset_str);

// Integer usage; outputs 'int(25)'
$unset_int += 25; // 0 + 25 => 25
var_dump($unset_int);

// Float/double usage; outputs 'float(1.25)'
$unset_float += 1.25;
var_dump($unset_float);

// Array usage; outputs array(1) {  [3]=>  string(3) "def" }
$unset_arr[3] = "def"; // array() + array(3 => "def") => array(3 => "def")
var_dump($unset_arr);

// Object usage; creates new stdClass object (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php)
// Outputs: object(stdClass)#1 (1) {  ["foo"]=>  string(3) "bar" }
$unset_obj->foo = 'bar';
var_dump($unset_obj);
?>
```